# Print the JSONPath & value in console.log in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to print JSON path in my console, 
Example

```
customer = {  
             "Name" : "Joe",
             "Address" : {
                          "Street" : "SomeStreet",
                          "City"   : "SomeCity"
                          }
            }

myfunction = function(myPath){
    console.log(myPath);
}

myfunction(customer.Address.City);
//This function should print "customer.Address.City" ( Not value "SomeCity")
```

Comment: why not directly do console.log('customer.Address.City'). I am not sure what you want to achieve. i suggest add more explanation to your question.

Comment: I receive a JSON Path to my method,I want to print both JSON path and the value in my report

Answer (score 0):

You can get values using json path, find below the simple snippet which could solve your problem, not tested with all the scenarios though.

```
const myfunction = function (myPath, customer) {
    const value = myPath.split(".").reduce((acc, cur) => {
        return acc[cur]
    }, customer)
    console.log('Path: ', myPath, ' Value: ', value)
}

const customer = {
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Address": {
        "Street": "SomeStreet",
        "City": "SomeCity"
    }
}
myfunction("Address.City", customer)
```

One thing to be noted here, you should not add your variable name in json path that's why I have skipped ***customer*** from json path.

Comment: Thank you for the solution , unfortunately I will not be able to use this solution because, if i go with this solution then I need to make this change to all calling programs, which is going to be huge task.

Comment: Then you have to make changes in your JSON structure to get it working. 
OR the simple hacky solution could be strip down "customer." from your JSON path and pass it to the function.